# VSCode doesn't recognize <transition> element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, transition

For some reason my VSCode has highlighted the transition element in red, which I take to mean it doesn't recognize this element. I'm not really sure what's going on here. And the code also doesn't work in that there is no transition or even any change with clicking the button at all. Thanks for your help!

> ```
> <!--Vuejs CDN-->
> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
>
> <title>Hello, world!</title>   </head>   <body>
> <div id='app'>
>   <button v-on:click='showThis = !showThis'>Swap</button>
>   <transition name='fade'>
>     <p v-if='showThis'>Then showThis is true!</p>
>   </transition>
> </div>
>
> <!-- Vuejs -->
> <script>
>   new Vue({
>     el:'#app',
>     data:{
>       showThis:true
>     }
>   })
> </script>
>
> <style>
> .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
>   transition: opacity .5s;
> }
> .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
>   opacity: 0;
> }
> </style>
>
> <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
> <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
> ```
>
> crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Please note that I have one file called index.html and that there is a bit of code above and below this. Also the body element got shifted in the code above, but it's there.

Comment: I added it to a github repo just in case: github.com/Taikon/prac5/blob/master/prac5%20transitions.html. I have also changed the user setting as per Debadatta. It works now in the browser, but the transition element is still highlighted as red in VSCode and Github for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check by adding the following lines in User Settings. Files->Preferences->Settings->User Settings

***"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"eslint.validate": [
  "javascript", 
  "javascriptreact",
  "vue"
]***

Comment: Also extremely likely this will fix it.

Comment: I added it to a github repo just in case: https://github.com/Taikon/prac5/blob/master/prac5%20transitions.html. I have also changed the user settings. It works now in the browser, but the transition element is still highlighted as red in VSCode and Github for some reason. Thanks a bunch for troubleshooting this! I have no idea how you know what to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is your  tag that is just a closing tag. Try creating `<head></head>` open and closing pair.